# Using grep on a continous/live stream of data

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, grep

Goal: I'm wanting to do live pattern matching for each line of incoming data from the `tail` command presented in the code below.

Issue: Although the `tail` command and `while-loop`  are functioning there seems to be no sort of pattern matching as the lines of data come in.

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
# Description: 
# 
# Usage: 
#

function interval () 
{ 
        echo $(date '+%y%m%d %H%M%S') $cnt 
        cnt=0 
} 

declare -i cnt=0 
trap interval SIGUSR1
target_file=${1:-access.log) 

shopt -s lastpipe 

tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep --line-buffered "20" | while read aline 
do 
        let cnt++ 

done < <( grep --line-buffered "20" )
```

Comment: What you couldn't resolve and what's issues with your code?

Comment: The `while` loop gets standard input from two sources, the second of which (the process substitution) doesn't generate any output.

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are here:

```
tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep --line-buffered "20" | while read aline 
do 
        let cnt++ 

done < <( grep --line-buffered "20" )
```

> Issue: Although the tail command and while-loop are functioning there seems to be no sort of pattern matching as the lines of data come in.

How do you know?  A lot of times in bash, the easiest way to figure out what is going wrong, is to split the pieces up and see what happens.  For example. if you run just

```
tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep --line-buffered "20"
```

you will be able to see what is passed into the while loop.  The pipe into the while loop will send the output of the above command into the while loop.  That is the input for it.  Another way to send input into a while loop is a process substitution which you are doing here:

```
done < <( grep --line-buffered "20" )
```

Your pipe into the while loop is providing the input.  This line is as well.  You should only use one of these methods.  However, this line doesn't do anything because it needs input itself.  If you run that command by itself, you will see the terminal hang waiting for your input.  Try running the following on the terminal by itself:

```
grep --line-buffered "20"
```

Nothing will happen.  So you are using 2 methods to send input into the while loop, and you should only use one:

```
tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep --line-buffered "20" | while read aline 
do 
        let cnt++ 
done
```

or...

```
while read aline 
do 
        let cnt++ 
done < <( tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep --line-buffered "20" )
```

Of course, there is an easier way to do all of this.  It appears you are trying to set the cnt variable to the number of lines in the output.  Instead of using a loop, try grep's -c option to *c*ount the lines for you.  Wrap the whole thing in a command substitution to set it the cnt variable:

```
cnt=$(tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep -c --line-buffered "20")
```